# Un équivalent français de "add insult to injury"

Tags: expressions

En anglais, il existe une expression idiomatique, *to add insult to injury*, qui signifie exactement ce qu'elle suggère : ajouter une insulte à une blessure.

Existe-t-il un équivalent en français ? J'ai pensé à "remuer le couteau dans la plaie", mais le sens y est moins précis.

Comment: "Remuer le couteau dans la plaie" convient très bien, de même que "pour couronner le tout..." et ses quelques synonymes. En effet, la phrase anglaise est à prendre comme une métaphore qui est équivalente à "To make matters worse...", qui veut bel et bien dire "empirer une situation déjà mauvaise".

Comment: Je rejoins MorganFR. C'est le sens de « remuer le couteau dans la plaie ». Je ne vois pas où tu perds la précision, à moins que tu ne t'attaques au sens premier (et que tu cherches « insulte » et « blessure ») de l'expression anglaise, auquel cas on n'aura pas d'équivalent tout fait en français.

Comment: Un article de [blogue d'André Racicot](http://andreracicot.ca/insulte-2/) offre quelques possibilités intéressantes, notamment `comble d'insulte` et `pour couronner le tout`. Par contre, ces suggestions sont beaucoup moins frappantes.

Comment: "l'insulte" est le petit truc en plus qui n'est douloureux que parce qu'on a été blessé avant, et qui se situe sur un plan différent (physique/social), alors que remuer le couteau dans la plaie, c'est juste insister sur le même plan (physique/physique).

Comment: "par dessus le marché" could be used too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Récapitulatif des propositions déjà effectuées :

> Remuer le couteau dans la plaie. (assez courante)
>   Pour couronner le tout.
>   Le comble d'insulte.
>   Par dessus le marché.
>   Doubler ses torts d'un affront.
>   La goutte d'eau qui fait déborder le vase
>   La cerise sur le sundae (Québec)
>   Ajouter l'affront à la douleur
>   Ajouter l'affront à la violence

Autres propositions :

> La cerise sur le gâteau (France)
>   Aggraver son cas. (si celui qui injure est jugé)
>   Le pompon (c'est le pompon!)
>   Aller outre mesure
>   Dépasser les bornes/limites (un peu éloigné)

Comment: Je vais partir sur "la cerise sur le gâteau", qui a le mérite de refléter la disproportion entre les deux affronts: la blessure et l'insulte, l'un n'étant grave que parce qu'il est précédé par l'autre.

Comment: Je ne connais pas le contexte dans lequel l'utiliser, mais j'a personnellement un faible pour "la goutte d'eau qui fait déborder le vase", qui est plus directe.
La cerise sur le gâteau marche tout aussi bien, mais il est employé au sens ironique.
Dans le sens non ironique, c'est le petit plus qui fait plaisir, comme "le clou du spectacle".

Comment: "Par dessus le marché", "Doubler ses torts d'affront", "Ajouter l'affront à la douleur" ok, par contre tout le reste est à la limite du contre-sens.

Answer (score 7):

> [Doubler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/doubler) ses [torts](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tort) d'un [affront](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/affront/1539/synonyme).

C'est une des solutions proposées à la [*Banque de dépannage linguistique*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2882). On a les deux éléments avec l'idée d'ajout (multiplier, dépasser ou associer à part égale, peut-être par opposition à un ajout *culminant*, comme au figuré avec la *cerise sur le [sundae](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4454)* (Québec) ou, différemment, avec la *goûte qui fait déborder le vase*) par une personne de l'*affront*, la parole ou l'acte méprisant, au *tort*, ce préjudice, qui peut être quelque chose de matériel...<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> On propose aussi : « *redoubler d'insultes, aller trop loin, dépasser la mesure,* [doubler ses torts d'un affront], *retourner (ou tourner) le fer dans la plaie, aggraver son cas, pour couronner le tout, et pour comble d'insulte, pour comble, etc.* » (BDL). C'est qu'il y a aussi l'idée de surenchère de l'action/du destin, et on a montré [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19774) qu'on peut la retrouver dans des phrases très similaires à l'expression en anglais, mais avec des paires de mots différents en compléments. Il faut constater que selon qu'on [glisse](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/add+insult+to+injury) davantage du fait d'une personne vers l'emploi au figuré ou abstrait, il faut adapter ; par exemple, avec un truc au figuré comme « My car barely started this morning, and to add insult to injury, I got a flat tire in the driveway. » (TFD), c'est plutôt le *comble* du malheur, de la malchance etc. à mon avis, alors que la solution en introduction implique une personne responsable de l'action et de l'insulte qui la suit. L'article à la *BDL* témoigne du fait qu'au Québec on calque directement la sémantique et le mot anglais (*injury*) avec l'emploi en pléonasme *ajouter l'insulte à l'injure* et donc on offre des solutions de rechange. D'autre part, à mon avis, *doubler qqc de qqc.*, avec son deuxième complément introduit par *de* est plus recherché et sans doute moins habituel qu'une expression avec *ajouter + à* ; n'empêche qu'on comprend spontanément (mon expérience). Dans la chronique [*Mots de tête : « ajouter l’insulte à l’injure »*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_autr8BKE-TUZytps&page=9AB8O_r7T1O4.html), Frèdelin Leroux (f), (L’Actualité langagière, volume 6, numéro 4, 2009, page 10) on traite du défi et des solutions et on indique que *doubler ses torts d'un affront* apparaissait dans le *Guide du traducteur*, Ottawa, A.T.I.O., 1972, p. 328 ([*Deux langues, six idiomes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aN4fAAAACAAJ&dq=inauthor:%22Ir%C3%A8ne%20de%20Buisseret%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSs-GPurrNAhVB94MKHRWUB9UQ6AEIJjAB), p. 299) d'[Irène de Buisseret](https://arts.uottawa.ca/crccf/fonds/P286) (1918-1971) ; on a déniché d'autres trucs comme « insulter l'âne jusqu'à la bride » etc. ; voir aussi un dictionnaire en [allemand](https://books.google.com/books?id=mpnwBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA142&ots=S2u9-QyFXF&dq=pour%20doubler%20ses%20torts%20d'un%20affront&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q=doubler%20ses%20torts%20d'un%20affront&f=false). Sur [*etymonline*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=insult) on réfère au latin *injuriae contumeliam addere* et donc on pourrait aussi s'appuyer directement sur l'expression. Selon le contexte on pourrait aussi parler d'une *ultime/suprême/totale* humiliation ou insulte, ou de [*jeter de l'huile sur le feu*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/huile/40576/locution?q=huile%20feu#162907), la métaphore illustrant le comportement de la personne qui *aggrave une querelle*. Il y a diverses manières d'exprimer les différentes facettes de l'expression.</sub>

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vu cette expression, est-ce du québécois ?

Comment: +1 for noting the important distinction between phrases involving an extra **aggravating** action (which is how I interpret your suggestion & how I use “add insult to injury” [also “rub salt in the wound"]) & those involving a **culminating** blow (like the difference between a “one-two punch” & a “knock-out punch” in boxing). Imo, even the BDL, with its options using “couronner” & “comble,” seems to be ignoring this important distinction, for those, imo, = “topped it [all] off with,” “the crowning blow/coup-de-grace” or even “the last straw,” none of which =“add insult to injury” as I use it.

Answer (score 4):

Une expression qui colle assez bien à l'anglais est **ajouter l'affront à la douleur**.

Aussi: **ajouter l'affront à la violence**.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vu cette expression, à quel point est-elle répandue ?

Comment: Ces expressions ne sont pas très répandues (google n'en trouve qu'une poignée d'occurrences) et sont d'un niveau de langue assez élevé. Elles ne posent cependant aucun problème de compréhension et « sonnent bien ». Il existe dans le même style « ajouter l'affront au préjudice », « ajouter l'affront à la blessure »...

Comment: "ajouter l'affront à la douleur" n'est pas super courant dans le sens où son utilisation peut sembler un peu littéraire, mais cette expression existe bel et bien et me semble vraiement être ce qu'il y a de plus proche, "ajouter l'affront à la violence" ne me dit rien du tout par contre (et s'éloigne du sens à mon avis).

Answer (score 0):

En fait, l’origine aurait été maladroitement déformée par le langage oral. « To add insult to injury » était à l’origine «to adding salt to injury », ajouter du sel à la blessure... qui fait fichtrement mal!

Comment: https://malaphors.com/2018/02/16/to-add-salt-to-injury/#:~:text=It%20is%20a%20congruent%20conflation,probably%20creating%20the%20mental%20mashup.